# Why the windows form is not getting closed

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use codeignIter. I use this code in view, why the window is not get close when I get click. I use this function

```
function setproduct(id,partno,nama,qtyscpend,ketsc,index) {
    var check=0;

    for (i=0;i<window.opener.$("#txtNoOfRow").val();i++) {

    if (id==window.opener.$("#ids_"+i).val()) {
        alert("Data Sudah Anda Pilih");
           check=1;
        }
    }

    if (check == 0){
        window.opener.document.getElementsByName("ids_"+index)[0].value = id;
        window.opener.document.getElementsByName("partno_"+index)[0].value = partno;
        window.opener.document.getElementsByName("partname_"+index)[0].value = nama;
        window.opener.document.getElementsByName("qtyscpend_"+index)[0].value = qtyscpend;
        window.opener.document.getElementsByName("ketsc_"+index)[0].value = ketsc;
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Then this for show data:

```
<?php 

    $no = 1;

    foreach($query->result() as $row) {?>

        <tr class="even gradeA">
            <td><?php echo $no  ;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->partno;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->partname;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->perpo;?></td>
            <td><?php echo date('d F Y',strtotime($row->sched)); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->qtyscpend;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->ketsc;?></td>
            <td align="center"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="setproduct('<?php echo $row->ids;?>','<?php echo $row->partno;?>','<?php echo $row->partname;?>','<?php echo $row->qtyscpend;?>','<?php echo $row->ketsc;?>','<?php echo $_GET['index'];?>');">Pilih</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php

        $no++;

    }

?>
```

What I want is when I click that align, the windows form is closed and send the variable like I wrote.

Comment: Debug it, before line `if (check == 0){` put `console.log(check)` or `alert(check)`.

Comment: Are you using Firefox?

Comment: Off topic - read up on xss.

Comment: hey @Tpojka 
i did wrote alert(check) and then it say = 0 why it is not getting closed yet

Comment: @David im using google chrome anyway

Comment: what is the mean by this 'the windows form is closed and send the variable like I wrote'

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can only close those windows that were previously open with script, it is a security precaution.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/close